# Is there a way to override only a portion of the function print_media_templates defined in wp-includes\media-template.php?

Tags: filters, wp-admin, media-library

I'd just like to -safely- change the visual presentation on the Attachments pop-up window, ie. move some of the main DIVs around. But it seems like the only hook is to the entire function which is very lengthy and I'm concerned as to long-term maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. Unless there's an `apply_filters()` call, you can't modify any of the output.

You mentioned "the only hook is to the entire function", but that's not the case either. There is a `do_action()` call at the end, but this is an action hook, so it only lets you run something at the end of the function. It doesn't let you modify the output.

To replace the `wp_print_media_templates` function you would need to perform a number of steps:

1. Copy the entire function to a new function in your theme or a plugin.
2. Add a callback to the `wp_enqueue_media` action hook that removes `wp_print_media_templates` from the [default hooks](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/7c7f95a8b22c1c9cb1fb70c69057175255c6a84c/wp-includes/media.php#L4904-L4906).
3. Inside that `wp_enqueue_media` callback, add your copied version of the function to the same hooks in place of `wp_print_media_templates`.

But this introduces a number of issues:

1. The JavaScript that powers the media library is expecting the HTML added by the original hook. If you modify this there's a chance that you'll break this JavaScript by moving or removing elements that are expected by the script.
2. You're now on the hook to keep your copy of the function up to date with any changes made by future WordPress versions. If you don't you may miss out on new features or cause the above issue by failing to add/change/remove elements that might be expected by updates to the script in WordPress.

Comment: Thanks. Then, can you suggest a way to target those elements via JS or jQuery? I added a script which works on the media library, but I cannot seem to be able to target this popup window.